# Event tracking data for event category is showing undefined in Google Analytics Real Time View while sending data using datalayer

Tags: google-analytics

I Pushed my data to datalayer in the following way,

dataLayer.push(
     { 
         'eventAction': 'product URL COPIED',
         'eventCategory':'product',
         'timestamp': Date.now()
    }
);

and I am able to track event in Real Time View but eventCategory is showing as undefined in Real-time>>Events section but eventAction is showing correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `eventCategory` as custom dimension so, it should be undefined for me.
After removing it from custom dimensions it works correctly.